# JavaScript : How get all post when scroll

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to get a posts when scroll, I can do that by add ID to div and when click it, We get my posts.

But i need when scroll, not when click to div.

how can convert this.

Suppose I have div and I want to fetch data and push data into that div. When the user scrolls within the div, the next set of data will be fetched and pushed into the div. How do I detect scroll bar position with jQuery? I don't want to use any plugin. I need jQuery code.

```
$window.scroll(function() {
        var pagiButton   = jQuery(this),
                theBlock     = pagiButton.closest('.mag-box'),
                theBlockID   = theBlock.get(0).id,
                theSection   = theBlock.closest('.section-item'),
                theTermID    = theBlock.attr('data-term'),
                currentPage  = theBlock.attr('data-current'),
                theBlockList = theBlock.find('.posts-list-container'),
                theBlockDiv  = theBlock.find('.mag-box-container'),
                options      = jQuery.extend( {}, window[ 'js_'+theBlockID.replace( 'tie-', 'tie_' ) ] ),
                theListClass = 'posts-items',
                isLoadMore   = false,
                sectionWidth = 'single';

        if( currentPage && options ){
            if( theTermID ){
                if( options[ 'tags' ] ){
                    options[ 'tags' ] = theTermID;
                }
                else{
                    options[ 'id' ] = theTermID;
                }
            }

            // Custom Block List Class
            if( options[ 'ajax_class' ] ){
                theListClass = options[ 'ajax_class' ];
            }

            // Check if the Button Disabled
            if( pagiButton.hasClass( 'pagination-disabled' ) ){
                return false;
            }

            // Check if the button type is Load More
            if( pagiButton.hasClass( 'load-more-button' ) ){
                currentPage++;
                isLoadMore = true;
            }

            // Next page button
            else if( pagiButton.hasClass( 'next-posts' ) ){
                currentPage++;
                theBlock.find( '.prev-posts' ).removeClass( 'pagination-disabled' );
            }

            // Prev page button
            else if( pagiButton.hasClass( 'prev-posts' ) ){
                currentPage--;
                theBlock.find( '.next-posts' ).removeClass( 'pagination-disabled' );
            }

            // Full Width Section
            if( theSection.hasClass( 'full-width' ) ){
                sectionWidth = 'full';
            }

            // Ajax Call
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : tie.ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action : 'jannah_blocks_load_more',
                    block  : options,
                    page   : currentPage,
                    width  : sectionWidth
                },
                beforeSend: function(data){

                    // Load More button----------
                    if( isLoadMore ){
                        pagiButton.html( tie.ajax_loader );
                    }
                    // Other pagination Types
                    else{
                        var blockHeight = theBlockDiv.height();
                        theBlockDiv.append( tie.ajax_loader ).attr( 'style', 'min-height:' +blockHeight+ 'px' );
                        theBlockList.addClass('is-loading');
                    }
                },
                success: function( data ){

                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    // Hide next posts button
                    if( data['hide_next'] ){
                        theBlock.find( '.next-posts').addClass( 'pagination-disabled' );
                        if( pagiButton.hasClass( 'show-more-button' ) || isLoadMore ){
                            pagiButton.html( data['button'] );
                        }
                    }
                    else if( isLoadMore ){
                        pagiButton.html( pagiButton.attr('data-text') );
                    }

                    // Hide Prev posts button
                    if( data[ 'hide_prev' ] ){
                        theBlock.find( '.prev-posts').addClass( 'pagination-disabled' );
                    }

                    // Posts code
                    data = data['code'];

                    // Load More button append the new items
                    if( isLoadMore ){
                        var content = ( '<ul class="'+theListClass+' posts-list-container clearfix posts-items-loaded-ajax posts-items-'+currentPage+'">'+ data +'</ul>' );
                        content = jQuery( content );
                        theBlockDiv.append( content );
                    }

                    // Other pagination Types
                    else{
                        var content = ( '<ul class="'+theListClass+' posts-list-container posts-items-'+currentPage+'">'+ data +'</ul>' );
                        content = jQuery( content );
                        theBlockDiv.html( content );
                    }

                    var theBlockList_li = theBlock.find( '.posts-items-'+currentPage );

                    // Animate the loaded items
                    theBlockList_li.find( 'li' ).hide().velocity('stop').velocity( 'transition.slideUpIn', {
                        stagger: 100,
                        duration: 500,
                        complete: function(){
                            tie_animate_element( theBlockList_li );
                            theBlockDiv.attr( 'style', '' );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            // Change the next page number
            theBlock.attr( 'data-current', currentPage );
        }
        return false;
    });
```

to get all posts when scrolling

Comment: We need a lot more than this to work on...

Comment: You'd really need to provide more information. But it sounds like you're talking about an "infinite scroll" type thing, which is covered all over this site. Here's one question: [Jquery infinite scroll - with div not scrollbar of body](//stackoverflow.com/q/10072216)

Comment: i see it but there are problem !

Answer (score 0):

try this to call the function ;)

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
    }
};
```